# Bootstrap Radio button : radio circle removal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap for my website. I have radio buttons and I am trying to use "Buttons" from bootstrap for the same.

```
<td style="margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom: 0px;font-size=12px;vertical-align:bottom;">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="topButtonDiv" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Home
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" ></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Home1
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" > </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Home2
        <input  type="radio" id="radio7"> </button>                
     </div>
</td>
```

The problem I am facing is that I still see the circles in the Radio button present, where as in the Bootstrap example, I see no such circles present.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-usage

Can you let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the version of css you've added. The same `btn-group` class works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/XmXZY/1/)

Comment: Huh, you were right. Looks like I downloaded a wrong version(not sure how as I got it from the same website). It works now.

Comment: Check that when `data-toggle="buttons"` is removed. The radio button comes back.

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative if the css version update is not working is to manually hide the radio button using css

```
[type='radio'] {
display: none; 
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when using react-bootstrap, providing a custom bsClass to the ToggleButton component.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup for bootstrap radio buttons is wrong, you make it like this:

```
<div class="radio">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
</label>
</div>
```

Furthermore you can't put a input element within a button element. That's invalid html.

Comment: I had label instead of button in my previous version. It did not work. So just changed the label into button to see if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

- wrap everything in a span with `data-toggle="buttons"`
- add `class="d-none"` in the input field

```
<span class="float-right" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label asp-for="ExpertiseLevel" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="juniorCheckbox">
         <input asp-for="ExpertiseLevel" type="radio" class="d-none" id="juniorCheckbox" value="JUNIOR" checked>
     Junior</label>

                    
     <label asp-for="ExpertiseLevel" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="expertCheckbox">
         <input asp-for="ExpertiseLevel" type="radio" class="d-none" id="expertCheckbox" value="EXPERT">
     Expert</label>
</span>
```