# React-Bootstrap Toggle Button is Failing to Hide the Radio Button Circle

Tags: radio-button, react-bootstrap, togglebutton

In my form, I want toggle buttons. The following code is copied from react-bootstrap docs on toggle buttons. However, the radio-button circles are displaying when they should be hidden. How do I hide them?

```
import ButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup'
import ToggleButton from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButton
```

'

```
<ButtonGroup>
   {radios.map((radio, idx) => (
    <ToggleButton
     key={idx}
     id={`radio-${idx}`}
     type="radio"
     variant={idx % 2 ? 'outline-success' : 'outline-danger'}
     name="radio"
     value={radio.value}
     checked={radioValue === radio.value}
     onChange={(e) => setRadioValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
                                    >
     {radio.name}
    </ToggleButton>
      ))}
 </ButtonGroup>
```

Comment: Experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `<ToggleButtonGroup />` component as the container. Set `type` to `radio`. Note that `name` is required when type is radio

See code below

```
<ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="radio">
  {radios.map((radio, idx) => (
    <ToggleButton
      key={idx}
      id={`radio-${idx}`}
      variant={idx % 2 ? 'outline-success' : 'outline-danger'}
      value={radio.value}
      checked={radioValue === radio.value}
      onChange={(e) => setRadioValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
    >
      {radio.name}
    </ToggleButton>
  ))}
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you

Comment: Did the exact same thing and it did not work for me. `react-bootstrap version 2.0.0-rc.0`

Comment: Did not work for me react-bootstrap 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but adding this to my CSS did the trick:

```
[type='radio'] {
  display: none; 
}
```

h/t to [this answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27367464/7004653)

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to occur temporarily when upgrading to new react-bootstrap (v1=>v2): https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5782

Some steps that can solve the issue:

1. Restart your react app
2. Clear cache (Google Chrome right click on refresh gives this option)
3. Restart docker container if applicable
4. Run npm list react-bootstrap to see if version is correct
5. Run npm ci for clean slate with your packages
6. If no combination of these works, file a separate issue or reply to issue linked above.

**Alternative solution** (not recommended)

```
.btn-group input[type='radio'] {
    display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually related to failing to include the stylesheet. I had this problem and the other answers didnt help but including the stylesheet fixed it for me

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

[React-Bootstrap CSS](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#css)

Answer (score 0):

Under **App.js** (or **src/index.js**) import the minified Bootstrap CSS:

```
// App.js

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./assets/styles/theme.css";
...
```

Then your **ToggleButtonGroup** component should look something like this:

```
// ToggleButtonGroupComponent.js
        
<ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options">
   {radios.map((radio, idx) => (
       <ToggleButton
          key={idx}
          id={`radio-${idx}`}
          type="radio"
          variant={idx % 2 ? 'outline-success' : 'outline-danger'}
          name="radio"
          value={radio.value}
          checked={radioValue === radio.value}
          onChange={(e) => setRadioValue(e.currentTarget.value)}>
          {radio.name}
       </ToggleButton>
    ))}
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

**React-Bootstrap CSS:** https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#css
**ToggleButtonGroup:** https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#uncontrolled